# multiple GROUP CONCAT

Tags: mysql, group-concat

i have sql data and query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/749bec/1

the result of current query is not what i need

```
SELECT 
satker.kode_satker,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(data.map) ,'-',value SEPARATOR '\n') as newvalue 
FROM satker 
left join data on data.kode_satker=satker.kode_satker 
GROUP BY data.kode_satker
```

because it show

```
kode_satker     newvalue
100     A-100 A-200 B-400 B-100
200     C-100 A-100 A-100
```

I need the new query show

```
kode_satker     newvalue
100     A-300 B-500
200     A-200 C-100
```

Any idea??

Comment: Consider handling display issues in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution with correct order of newvalue

SELECT kode_satker,group_concat(map,'-',valuesum order by map) as new_value
From ( 
Select satker.kode_satker, data.map, sum(data.value) as valuesum
FROM satker 
left join data 
on data.kode_satker=satker.kode_satker
group by satker.kode_satker, data.map) t
Group by kode_satker

Result:
kode_satker new_value
100.            A-300,B-500
200.            A-200,C-200

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery, you cannot "nest" aggregation without one; basic structure is

```
SELECT a, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(b, '-', x_sum)) 
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, SUM(x) AS x_sum 
    FROM some_table 
    GROUP BY a, b
) AS q 
GROUP BY a
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT kode_satker,GROUP_CONCAT(map order by map separator '\n') as newmap,GROUP_CONCAT(xval order by map separator '\n') as rp FROM (SELECT 
satker.kode_satker,data.map,sum(value) as xval
FROM satker 
left join data on data.kode_satker=satker.kode_satker 
GROUP BY data.kode_satker,map ) as q group by kode_satker